# Environment refresh for Primavera P6

Tags: primavera

Please suggest a easy method to take backup of P6 application configuration details(configuration and authentication tab). 
I need to take backup of this configuration before importing production data into the develpment environment. Currently i am taking screenshots of each options which is very exhausting.(I'm new to Primavera). Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the configuration data is held in the `ADMIN_CONFIG` table. If you are using SQL Server you can use the SQL Profiler to watch the queries being issued by the admin tool.

Comment: Here I am using Oracle DB. Also how configuration details like database settings,authentication details, connection pool details will be there in DB? Is there any way to directly export the configuration details and import it back after DB refresh.

Comment: i digged up admin_config table and got the config details in BLOB format. I am wondering if i can take a backup of only this table and reimport it again after env refresh - will the same configuration details set in Primavera? Also is there any other table having config details?

Comment: You should be able to backup and restore as you describe, as far as I can tell that table is the source of configuration data used by Primavera. I'm not aware of any other tables holding configuration data, but it would probably be worth experimenting with a test environment to see if you are able to successfully recover your configuration by restoring the `admin_config` table.

Comment: Thank you Jon.. it worked.. restoring admin_config table contains all the old configuration settings before db refresh.